# MariaDB update column based on previous registry value

Tags: mariadb

I have this table:

**Visitor**

| id | page_id | count | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2022-12-31 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 2023-01-01 |

But I wanted to update the count column, sequentially, respecting the value of the last line.

The lines with ID 1 and 2 are correct. But I intend to correct the values ​​of the following lines depending on the last page_id value in the year 2022.

**Visitor**

| id | page_id | count | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2022-12-31 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 1 | 26 | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | 1 | 27 | 2023-01-01 |

Comment: Can you confirm what version of MySQL you are using? `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Also, can you assume `id` order is the order of the sequence?

Comment: 5.5.68-MariaDB. The ID is just part of the example, it is not related to the count. I can use the ID to search for the previous ID of the same page_id.

Comment: Okay, sorry, my solution depends on using MySQL 8.0. Please understand that MariaDB and MySQL are different products, and they are not compatible.

Comment: Also consider that MariaDB 5.5 has been unsupported for 3.5 years by now! https://endoflife.date/mariadb